# How to run Cron Job on Shared Hosting? (Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, lumen

I am trying to implement a cron job in my lumen project. I have BookingMaster Table when a user is creating a booking I am setting the default status to **B** means booked in the table. in the day of booking I am trying to update the status to **I** to database means In-progress. When I am doing this locally the cron is running perfectly and the status is also updating.

But when I moved this code to my shared hosting it is not working any more. The cron is not updating the status in database.

Location Of the BookingUpdate.php is - app/Console/Commands/BookingUpdate.php

BookingUpdate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Helpers;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\BookingMaster;

class BookingUpdate extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'BookingUpdate:booking-update';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Cron for Booking Update';

    public static $process_busy = false;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(){
        if (self::$process_busy == false) {
            self::$process_busy = true;
            $where['status'] = 'B';
            $update = BookingMaster::updateRecord(6,$where);
            self::$process_busy = false;             
            echo 'Done';
               return true;
        } else {
            if ($debug_mode) {
                error_log("Process busy!", 0);
            }

            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

karnel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\BookingUpdate',

    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Cron Job Command :

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/rahulsco/public_html/api.pawsticks/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Using Logs to debug

Comment: There is no error in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a several issues with your code not running in Cron.

- Maybe the correct path to PHP is not on the `/usr/local/bin/php` try running Cron with just `php -q`
- Some systems require the script to start with `#!/usr/bin/env php` or some similar combination.
- There is a space in your cron command on this part `artisan schedule:run` so it might work once you put your command in quotation marks and escape spaces
  `php -q "/home/rahulsco/public_html/api.pawsticks/artisan\ schedule:run" 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Finally, if anything else fails I would try logging something to a file and checking after cron runs, maybe there is some other error in your directory configuration causing your script to fail before writing to database and the cron is running fine...

Comment: After adding the command i found no errors in the error log but database is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

In app/Console/kernel.php, the schedule function should be like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command('BookingUpdate:booking-update')->daily();
}
```

Then your BookingUpdate process will run daily at midnight. There are various other options to schedule your task as mentioned here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Also, you can simply execute the cron manually at any time using: `php artisan BookingUpdate:booking-update`

PS. Replace `BookingUpdate:booking-update` with `$signature` variable value defined in your command class you need to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with shared server - linux with laravel/lumen API.

It's working seamlessly.

```
lynx -dump "here your url for api or any external url you want call"
```

Note: Wrap your URL inside double quote